# Having problems using delete method in MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, react-props, mern

I am practicing using the MERN stack for the first time. I was using this tutorial loosely as a guide but I made some of my own tweaks to make the app function as a social media site. My backend code works fine, as I've tested it using Postman and it gives me the desired result. But when I put the button on my React project and call the onClick method, nothing happens with the request. Every other method works as desired in my project besides this one.

Feed.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
// import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

const renderCard = props => {
   return (
    <>
      <Card style={{ width: '30rem', marginLeft:'auto', marginRight:'auto'}}>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{props.username} says: </Card.Title>
        <Card.Text> {props.text}</Card.Text>
       <Link to = {"/edit/"+ props._id}>
        <Button style={{marginRight: '10px'}} variant="secondary">Edit {props.username}'s Profile</Button>
       </Link>
        <Button variant="danger" onClick = {props.deletePost(props.id)}>Delete Post</Button>{' '}
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    <br/>
    </>
     )
}
export default class Feed extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.deletePost = this.deletePost.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      postedBy: '',
      username: '',
      text: '',
      id: '',
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9998/posts/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ posts: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }


  deletePost(id) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:9998/posts/'+id)
      .then(response => { console.log(response.data)});

    this.setState({
      posts: this.state.posts.filter(element => element._id !== id)
    })
  }

   render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1 style = {{marginLeft:'auto', marginRight:'auto'}}>Home</h1>
      <hr/>
    <div>{this.state.posts.map(renderCard)} </div> 
    </div>
    )
   }
}
```

Posts.js (route)

```
const router = require("express").Router();
let Post = require("../models/posts.model");

// Get all posts

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
    Post.find()
      .then((posts) => res.json(posts))
      .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error " + err));
  });

// Add new posts

router.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
    const text = req.body.text; 
    const photo = req.body.photo;
    const likes = req.body.likes;
    const comments = req.body.comments;
    const created = req.body.created;
    const username = req.body.username;

    const newPost = new Post ({
        text,
        photo,
        likes,
        comments,
        created,
        username
    });

    newPost.save()
      .then(() => res.json("Post added!"))
      .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err))

});


router.route("/:id").delete((req, res) => {
    Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
      .then(() => res.json("Post deleted!"))
      .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err))
});



  module.exports = router;
```

I believe the issue lies within this line and I'm using props incorrectly. I expect this code to delete the post from the MongoDB database and delete the card/post from the UI.

```
        <Button variant="danger" onClick = {props.deletePost(props.id)}>Delete Post</Button>{' '}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about that line. What you are doing is calling `props.deletePost(props.id)` on render instead of `onClick`

Try wrapping it with anonymous function like `onClick={() => props.deletePost(props.id)}`

**Edit:**

You are setting renderCard here and passing in individual `post` as props variable

```
<div>{this.state.posts.map(renderCard)} </div>
```

One potential solution would be to pass `deletePost` to `renderCard` function like

```
.map((post) => renderCard({ deletePost: this.deletePost, ...post}))
```

and keep renderCard the same

Comment: Ok I tried that line of code and I get the following error in the console:Uncaught TypeError: props.deletePost is not a function. When I try onClick = {() => {this.deletePost(props._id)}} I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deletePost')

Comment: Try onClick = {() => {this.props.deletePost(props._id)}}

Comment: Now I'm getting the error "Feed.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')"

Comment: @vshjnsfns I updated the answer, hope it solves your issue

Comment: I ended up making deletePost a separate page on its own as a work around since this was time sensitive, but I will try this approach.